# How to detect screensaver state in Ubuntu 16

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, ubuntu-gnome, screensaver

I have a script that needs to detect whether or not the screen is locked and saver is active.

In Ubuntu 12, I used to call `gnome-screensaver-command -q`. This command is still available in 16.04, but it always reports the screensaver is inactive.

I tested it by running this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo "Checking..."
    gnome-screensaver-command -q;
    sleep 1;
done
```

and then locked my screen for several seconds. It reports "The screensaver is inactive" for the entire time.

What changed in Ubuntu 16.04 to break this, and how do I get an accurate report of whether or not the screen is locked?

Edit: I'm using Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Unity as desktop environment

```
qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.IsLocked
```

will print `true` if the screen is locked and `false` otherwise

Comment: I'm not, I'm using Gnome.